# Dynamically Replace Files During Build in 'angular.json' Using Env Variables

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, environment-variables, angular-cli

We have an Angular 7 project and are trying to replace files dynamically without definitely all of the different files in the `angular.json` file. For instance, when you use the `--prod` flag after `ng build`, `angular.json` will replace `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.

We have another file that contains application specific configuration settings that change depending on the installation. For instance, if we are deploying the project for one client, we may want to run `ng build --prod --configuration=clientOne` to use that client's specific config file. In this scenario, you'd expect to see something like the below in the `angular.json` file.

```
"clientOne": {
  "fileReplacements": [{
    "replace": "src/app/clientSettings.ts",
    "with": "src/app/clientSettings.clientOne.ts"
  }]
}
```

**Here's the main question**: How can we ask `angular.json` to replace the `clientSettings.ts` file with other files based on environment flags, such as `--configuration=clientOne`, without actually specifying each option in the `angular.json`. We don't want other developers using the software knowing what installations we have and we don't need to know which ones they have. We want to replace files dynamically without specifying what they are anywhere. We could git ignore the file but that doesn't seem practical.

Comment: Angularly-speaking you have no other solution. For that, it's either your server configuration, a Node script, GIT, etc. But Angular only uses the `angular.json` file to do that.

Comment: I had a feeling. Thanks.